# pandas reading JSON with chunk size:

Tags: json, pandas

I have JSON file which I need to load into memory via chunks.

consider this `file.json` example:

```
[{"weekly_report_day":"2019-12-30T00:00:00","project_id":"2","actions":1,"users":1,"event_id":1},
    {"weekly_report_day":"2019-12-30T00:00:00","project_id":"2","actions":1,"users":1,"event_id":1},
    {"weekly_report_day":"2019-12-30T00:00:00","project_id":"2","actions":1,"users":1,"event_id":1},
    {"weekly_report_day":"2019-12-30T00:00:00","project_id":"2","actions":1,"users":1,"event_id":1},
    {"weekly_report_day":"2019-12-30T00:00:00","project_id":"2","actions":1,"users":1,"event_id":1},
    {"weekly_report_day":"2019-12-30T00:00:00","project_id":"2","actions":1,"users":1,"event_id":1}
]
```

THen I want to use pandas `read_json` function combined with chunksizes.:

```
import pandas as pd

file = "file.json"

dtype = {"weekly_report_day": str, "project_id": str, "actions": int, "event_id": int}

chunked = pd.read_json(file, orient = 'records', dtype=dtype, chunksize = 1, lines = True)

for df in chunked:
    print(df)
```

This however returns an error.

I would like to ask for suggestion (I need to use chunks, as the original data are very huge).

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Also, the `json` you shared is invalid. Please update the correct one.

Comment: Updated, really need to use chunksize

Comment: The JSON in the question is not `line-delimited-json`.  `lines` + `chunksize` can only work with `line-delimited-json`.